# Read command line and recvfrom simultaneously in C

Tags: c, command-line, udp

In order to build a UDP chat, I need to send a message and at the same time, receive messages. For the moment, I am trying to receive messages and  to read the command line, print the message. Moreover, I want to call a function `func()` every 10 seconds.

This is what I have tried:

```
  fd_set readfds;
  struct timeval timeout;
  char buf[100];

  while(1){
    FD_ZERO(&readfds);
    FD_SET(sock_fd,&readfds);

    timeout.tv_sec = 10;
    timeout.tv_usec = 0;

    if(select(sock_fd +1, &readfds,NULL,NULL,&timeout) != 0){
        receiveMessages(sock_fd);
        memset((void*)buf,0,100);
        if(read(sock_fd,(void*)buf,100)!=-1){
          printf("Message : %s\n", buf );
        }
    }else{
        func();
    }
 }
```

In the `receiveMessages()`function, only one function is called: `recvfrom()`.

The functions `receiveMessages(sock_fd)` and `func()`are correctly called every 10 seconds but the command line is never read, so the message is never printed. What did I miss ?

Comment: First of all, you have set up a socket and associated it with sock_fd, yes?  

Secondly, is `func()` called *exactly* every 10 seconds?  If I'm not mistaken that would indicate `select` is *always* returning due to reaching the timeout... ie, `readfds` is never becoming ready.  
Which leads me to reiterate my first question...  
You probably want `man socket`.

Comment: I did associate the socket with sock_fd and yes the function `func()` is exactly called after 10 seconds. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Probably want to `man read` too.  Hint: you don't always get back as many bytes as you ask for.

Comment: Thank your for your answer, I will read the manual a second time.

Finally, the message is never printed because the "resource is temporarily unavailable". 

I guess something is wrong with read().

Comment: Nothing is wrong with `read()`, but a number of things are wrong with your code. Start by reading up on what `select()` returns, `FD_ISSET()`, and thinking about what happens when `read()` returns 100. And why you're calling `read()` there at all if `receiveMessages()` is also reading from the socket...